# Login no Wordpress com WebService (AD)

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Tenho um página em PHP que conecta a um WebService e efetua a validação do usuário no AD.

Gostaria que esta pagina fosse chamada quando fosse digitado a o URL do site feito em WordPress, pois nela crio os cookies:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {
if (empty($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['senha']) ) {
 $error = 'Preencha todos os campos.';
} else {
 $client = new SoapClient('http://endereco-do-webservices/servico.asmx?WSDL', array('login'=> "usuario-servico",'senha'=> "******"));
    $vars = $client->Autentica(array('login' => stripslashes($_POST['login']), 'senha' => $_POST['senha']));
    if($vars->AutenticaResult == true) {
  $var = $_POST['login'];
        $dominio = preg_split('/\\\/', $var, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if($dominio[0]==$var){
            $dominio[0] = 'meu-dominio';
            $dominio[1] = $var;
        }
  $search = $client->BuscaLogin(array('dominio'=>$dominio[0],'login' => $dominio[1]));
  $email = $search->BuscaLoginResult->Mail;
  $nome = $search->BuscaLoginResult->Nome;
  $dominiofin = $search->BuscaLoginResult->Dominio;
  setcookie("MyAuth", 'true', time()+50400);
  setcookie("MyMailAuth", $email, time()+50400);
  setcookie("MyNomeAuth", $nome, time()+50400);
  setcookie("MyDominioAuth", $dominiofin, time()+50400);
  header("location: /meu-site");
 } else {
  $error = 'Login inválido';
 }
}
}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=10" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
  <title>Verifica Login</title>
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/auth.css"-->
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/less.css"-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body class="auth">

 <?php if($error) {
echo '<script>window.alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
} ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/mylogo.png" alt="">
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" />
 <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" />
 <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Que são validados no header.php do tema:

```html
<?php 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['AGAuth'])) {
 $url = bloginfo('template_url');
 header('Location:'.$url.'?page_id=73');
 exit();
}
?>
```

Com ligar um registro da tabela wp_posts a uma página PHP na pasta do tema.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de uma `página` pra isso, pode só rodar o código em um `hook` bem cedo na inicialização, como [`after_setup_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/), por exemplo:

```
// no arquivo functions.php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'inicializa_cookies' );
function inicializa_cookies() {
    setcookie("MyAuth", 'true', time()+50400);
    // etc
}
```

Nesse caso o código rodaria em 100% dos page loads, logo que o tema é carregado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Mas quero setar os cookies somente quando for informados um login e senhas validado no AD. Por isso queria executar um página que já existe e faz a validação.

Comment: A resposta do AD vai pra uma URL específica? Como o WP sabe que recebeu essa informação?

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloquei o código da página que faz a validação no AD. Na verdade a página faz e validação e funciona corretamente. O que preciso é sempre que acessar o site o WordPress redirecione para esta página que se chama autentica.php. Se o usuário fo valido ser criado os cookies e o acesso concedido.